# Set QGraphicsScene's widget coordinates from mouse

Tags: qt, user-interface

I have a graphics scene and a view,

```
myScene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
ui->graphicsView->setScene(myScene);
..
myWidget = new QGraphicsWidget();
```

and I want to place my wdget where my mouse is, i.e.:

```
myWidget->setPos(ui->graphicsView->mapFromGlobal(QCursor::pos()));
```

I mean, I do not want to subclass my QGraphicsScene or ui->graphicsView. I just want to pass mouse position to my Widget. Yet, the line above do not place it under the cursor, and I wonder why !?

Can I map cursor position to the scene coordinates ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

```
QPoint viewPoint = ui->graphicsView->mapFromGlobal(QCursor::pos());
QPointF scenePoint = ui->graphicsView->mapToScene(viewPoint);
myWidget->setPos(scenePoint);
```